# Extraer datos de un array en una variable y separar los datos

Tags: php, array, explode

Soy nuevo en el tema de php y necesito sacar un dato por "echo" de un array que contiene direcciones ip pero solo necesito los 2 primeros parámetros de la dirección ip.

Por ejemplo 192.168.1.1 necesitaría sacar 192 y 168 por separado en 2 variables diferentes, se que tengo que utilizar explode para separar los datos, lo que no tengo claro es como tomar una posición concreta de un array y meterlo en una variable para poder hacer el explode.

y por ultimo ¿como podria meter esos datos, osea los 2 primeros campos de la dirección ip en una sola variable de tipo string?

Espero haberme explicado bien

Hasta el momento he conseguido hacer esto pero no me funciona.

```
$ContadorVisitasHoy ="SELECT distinct ip FROM contador2 where Fecha ='$FechaHoy'";
            $SqlContador = mysqli_query( $conexion, $ContadorVisitasHoy ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
            
            while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $SqlContador ))
            {

                $porciones = explode('.', $columna);
                
                $NumeroUno = $var_export($porciones[0]);
                $NumeroDos = $var_export($porciones[1]);
                $direccionIp = $NumeroUno.$NumeroDos;
                
                

                echo "</br>";

            }
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada una direccion ip no es un array, es un string.

Segundo si necesitas obtener las dos primeras secciones de la ip puedes convertir el string a un array usando como separadores los puntos.

***Ejemplo:***

```php
$ip_string = '192.168.1.1';

$num_array = explode('.',$ip_string);

var_export($num_array);
```

***Output:***

```
array (
  0 => '192',
  1 => '168',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '1',
)
```

Como podras observar tiene un array con 4 indices numericos que van de 0 a 3, entonces para obtener el primer valor y el segundo puedes hacer esto:

```php
var_export($num_array[0]);
echo PHP_EOL;
var_export($num_array[1]);
```

***output***

```
'192'
'168'
```

como podras observar estoy accediendo a la primera posicion y a la segunda.

Entonces para unir dos elementos de un array en una variable utilizaras el operador de union `.` que es el punto, ejemplo:

```php
$texto = $num_array[0].$num_array[1];
var_export($texto);
```

***Output:***

```
'192168'
```

Como podras observar hemos tomado los dos valores y lo hemos concatenado

***Nota:*** [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-export.php) es un metodo que muestra/imprime los datos por pantalla de una variablese usa para hacer debug paso a paso y ver el contenido de la variable...

Comment: @neofilo la programacion de trata en un 95% de investigar, estudiar y probar... y el resto del 5% ver anime... demuestra que hiciste en ese 95%...

Comment: @neofilo tienes que hacer una pregunta nueva, no puedes estar cambiando de pregunta en un mismo post.

Comment: Continuo en el siguiente enlace:

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557748/extraer-2-primeros-campos-de-una-ip

Comment: recuerda marcas como resueltas las preguntas...