# Extraer 2 primeros campos de una IP

Tags: php, ip

Tengo el siguiente Codigo:

```
 $ContadorVisitasHoy ="SELECT distinct ip FROM contador2 where Fecha ='$FechaHoy'";
            $SqlResult  = mysqli_query( $conexion, $ContadorVisitasHoy ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
            
            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $num_array = explode('.',$currentip);
    $texto = $num_array[0].'.'.$num_array[1]; 
    var_export($texto);
}
```

Lo que trato de hacer es lo siguiente, teniendo una dirección ip que me devuelve la consulta SQL ($columna) ejemplo del resultado 192.168.0.1, 192.169.0.1...., necesito sacar las 2 primeras partes de cada dirección ip que tiene la base de datos. EJ: 192.168 , 192.169....
Dichos campos los necesito meter en una variable de tipo String para poder compararlas con determinadas ips concretas.

Me da error la linea: `$num_array = explode('.',$columna);`

El error es el siguiente:

> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Espero me puedan ayudar y haberme explicado bien.

Comment: *Me da error la linea: $num_array = explode('.',$columna);* donde está eso en tu código? porqué el `;`? prueba poniendo `.` en vez de eso. O también haz un `echo` de cada variable y coméntanos qué es lo que te sale.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev esta fue su anterior pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557716/extraer-datos-de-un-array-en-una-variable-y-separar-los-datos

Comment: ¿Por qué se eliminó la respuesta de abajo?

Comment: El usuario la elimino por lo que le comente, que se adelanto a dar una respuesta y que el usuario no ha respondido a los comentatarios... y el bot de comunidad suele meter un voto negativo en ese caso... y cree que soy yo el que le metio el voto negativo XD....

Comment: ¿El bot de la comunidad? ¿Está seguro de lo que dice?

Comment: No se, pero a mi me ha pasado que en menos de 3 segundos ma aparece un voto negativo cuando alguna preguntas no cumplen el criterio de las normas... si es algun troll que mal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Parte 1:** Trabajando y mejorando los concepto:

Por que nombras `$SqlContador` el resultado de una consulta? esto es incorrecto; cuando nombramos variables debemos ser objetivos.

```php
$ContadorVisitasHoy ="SELECT distinct ip FROM contador2 where Fecha ='$FechaHoy'";
$SqlContador = mysqli_query( $conexion, $ContadorVisitasHoy ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
```

entonces en realidad deberia llamarce por ejemplo(`$SqlResult`):

```php
$ContadorVisitasHoy ="SELECT distinct ip FROM contador2 where Fecha ='$FechaHoy'";
$SqlResult = mysqli_query( $conexion, $ContadorVisitasHoy ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
```

Esto hace más cuerente, amigable y legible el codigo.

Luego, si aunque en este caso estas trayendo una sola columna, en realidad el `while` recorre verticalmente las filas; entonces el codigo deberia de ser:

```php
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult))
{
    var_export($row);
}
```

---

***Parte 2:*** Uso de [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) e [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

*El error que reportaste:* El problema es que `explode` solo trabaja con `string` entonces `$columna` no es un `string`; es un `array` por que estas trabajando con [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

*vease lo que se indica en la documentacion:*

> Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o
> ambos

Segun uses `MYSQLI_NUM` o `MYSQLI_ASSOC` como segundo parametro, por defecto

*por ejemplo al hacer esto:*

```php
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult,'usar MYSQLI_NUM o MYSQLI_ASSOC'))
{
    var_export($row);
}
```

el valor de `$columna` son todas las columnas del query en la fila entonces asumiendo que es un array como se indica en la documentacion, el output puede ser (`MYSQLI_NUM`):

```
[
    0 => 'la IP' //la ip que esta en la base de datos. OJO columna '0'
]
```

si fuese asociativo (`MYSQLI_ASSOC`);

```
[
    'ip' => 'la IP' //la ip que esta en la base de datos. OJO columna 'ip'
]
```

Usar el var_export o var_dump te indicara que es realmente lo que estas obteniendo de la base de datos y en que formato viene el array.

---

***Parte 3:*** solucionado el problema/error:

para solucionar el error basta con primero leer la columna usando el indice del array, este caso forzare el formato asociativo:

```php
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $currentip = $row['ip'];
}
```

una vez esto tendremos en `$currentip` el `string` de la ip en formato `'192.168.0.1'`

si haces explode, obtendras un array en el formato que te explique en la anterior [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/557728/46896) que te di.

la idea de usar el punto para concatenar los primeros 2 numeros de la ip era para evitar el uso de `implode` ya que implode volvera a unir TODOS los elementos del array y no solo el primero y segundo como indicas...

*quedari asi:*

```php
$num_array = explode('.',$currentip);
$texto = $num_array[0].'.'.$num_array[1]; //no debes usar implode aqui.
var_export($texto);
```

*Output:*

```
'192.168' // sin las comillas, esto es solo para indicar que es un string.
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder pero sigo atascado en el mismo punto, me dice que tengo que meter en explode un string no un array como estamos metiendo en este caso. Espero me puedan atudar, es una tonteria de codigo pero no consigo avanzar.

Comment: y que has hecho???

Comment: He modificado todo lo que me comentabas que estaba mal y he utilizado la formula que me has puesto pero me da error al intentar sacar los datos de la ip.

Comment: @neofilo segun lo que veo te comiste la asignacion `$currentip = $row['ip'];` que debe estar debajo del while no se si estas prestandole atencion a lo que estas programando pero para poder usar una variable tienes que declararla... y el error que reportas no corresponde a lo que te he explicado que hagas... hay cosas que estas haciendo a medias y por eso no te sale ... revisa nuevamente todo ...

Comment: Actualiza tu post no se que tienen nuevo hecho...